# Artifactory as docker Registry - docker-remote-cache stays empty

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry

i finally managed to get Artifactory 5.1 running as a docker Registry with nginx in front as Reverse Proxy using the subdomain method with a wildcard SSL certificate.

I have the predefinded set of docker repositories configured:
docker-local - repo
docker-remote - remote-repo
docker - virtual repo

I'm able to login with docker cli and i also can push and pull images to and from docker. as mentioned in JFrog Docs.

I think my "docker-remote" doesn't work - it stays at 0 byte with 0 artifacts in it.

If i pull something that isn't in my local repo i would have guessed that it is pulled from docker.io and cached in docker-remote but it seems its simply pulled from docker.io - thats it.

Do i have to configure something? Did i miss something or do i have to configure Replication ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: are you sure that your docker CLI is properly configured and pulling from Artifactory? when running docker images, do you see the image are coming from Artifactory

Comment: No i'm not sure but im locked out from docker.io and locked in into my private artifactory docker repo. Is there something else i have to to that my docker cli uses my repo instead of docker.io?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure your Docker CLI to use Artifactory as its registry, follow the instructions [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-GettingStartedwithArtifactoryProOn-Prem). Make sure to perform the steps listed under "Configuring Your Docker Client".

There are a couple of things you can do to check whether you docker CLI is using Artifactory as its registry:

- Use the [docker info](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/info/) command to see what registry is configured
- Look at the Artifactory request and access [logs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Log+Files) and look for requests from the Docker CLI
- Images fetched from docker.io should be present in the remote repository
- Make sure the images you are pulling are not stored in the local Docker cache

Comment: ok - finally got it working
problem was it didn't work sometimes - i have no clue why.

finally something like `docker pull <art_url>/alpine:latest` pulls the right image and uses docker-remote repo thx

Comment: great to hear that. please mark this question as resolved for the sake of other users

Comment: Emphasis on "Make sure the images you are pulling are not stored in the local Docker cache"! Otherwise it seems that only the manifest JSON file gets cached.